# Second function not executing after first await function

Tags: c#, async-await

I am calling two methods using async await. But only first one is executing. I want both function should run asynchronously. Because second function's input is not depend on the first function's execution. Could someone suggest here what actually I am missing here.

First function executes successfully, there is no exception occurred while executing first function.

Here is details regarding my code:

```
    if (MoveCardEntity.Error.Code == Constant.API_ERROR_CODE_SUCCESS)
                if (LoggedInUserSession.CustomerConfigPermission.IsNotificationsEnabled)
                    RaiseCardGroupNotification(MoveCardModel, MoveCardInputmodel).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return Json(MoveCardEntity, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
private async Task RaiseCardGroupNotification(MoveCard moveCard, MoveCardInput moveCardInput)
    {
        var account = GetPayerAccountsById(moveCard.AccountId.Value);
        var currentCardGroupName = Request.Form[Constant.CURRENT_CARD_GROUP_NAME].ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string targetCardGroupName = moveCardInput.TargetNewCardGroupName;
        int[] cardIdList = new[] { moveCard.CardId.Value };
        string[] cardPansList = new[] { moveCard.PAN };


        var cardList = _cardServiceEx.GetCardListByIds(account, cardIdList, LoggedInUserSession.UserName);
        targetCardGroupName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cardList.FirstOrDefault().CardGroupName) ? cardList.FirstOrDefault().CardGroupName : string.Empty;
        cardPansList = new string[] { cardList.FirstOrDefault().FullPan };

        var user = new UserDto
        {
            UserUuid = LoggedInUserSession.UserName,
            DisplayName = LoggedInUserSession.DisplayName,
            Locale = LoggedInUserSession.PreferredLanguage,
        };
        //new card group notification
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(moveCardInput.TargetNewCardGroupName))
        {
            await RaiseNewCardGroupAddedNotification(account, user, moveCardInput.TargetNewCardGroupName).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await RaiseCardAddedToCardGroupNotification(account, user, currentCardGroupName, cardPansList, cardList.ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            targetCardGroupName = Request.Form[Constant.TARGET_CARD_GROUP_NAME].ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            await RaiseMoveCardGroupNotification(account, user, currentCardGroupName, moveCardInput.TargetCardGroupId.Value, targetCardGroupName, cardPansList, cardList.ToList()).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
    }

private async Task RaiseNewCardGroupAddedNotification(AccountDto account, UserDto user, string newCardGroupName)
        {
            var dto = new RaiseCardGroupsNewNotificationDto
            {
                CardGroupNameNew = newCardGroupName
            };
            await _cardGroupNotificationRaiseService.NewAsync(account, user, dto).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
private async Task RaiseCardAddedToCardGroupNotification(AccountDto account, UserDto user, string cardGroupName, string[] cardPans, IList<CardDto> cardDtoList)
        {
            var dto = new RaiseCardGroupsAddCardsNotificationDto
            {
                CardGroupName = cardGroupName,
                CardPans = cardPans,
                CardDtoList = cardDtoList
            };
            await _cardGroupNotificationRaiseService.AddCardsAsync(account, user, dto).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
```

Comment: does the first operation complete (eventually)? the second operation won't be started until the first completes; is there an exception? etc

Comment: no there is no exception in the first one, first function executes successfully. actually both function should run asynchronously at same time.

Comment: k, here's the thing; it is **very unlikely** that the compiler is broken here, so: `await` probably works *just fine*; that means that the *most likely* thing here is that your code is failing, presumably with an exception; if I had to guess, I'd wager on `cardList.ToList()`, because it is the only non-trivial code between the two; what is `cardList` here? is it `null`? can it be iterated successfully? etc; so once again: are you sure there isn't an exception?

Comment: so you want `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2)`

Comment: Everything here is *already* executing asynchronously; do you perhaps mean "concurrently"? Can you please clarify exactly what is happening right now, vs what you *expect* to happen right now, because: it all looks just fine

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for configuring the `await` with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`? This method is used mainly in library code. If you are not writing a library, you shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the confusion here is:

> actually both function should run asynchronously at same time

It sounds like you're asking for them to run concurrently, but "asynchronous" and "concurrent" are almost entirely unrelated. In *this* case you can probably cheat by using `Task.Run` to run one of them over on the thread-pool, then just `await` back to it so that you await both completions:

```cs
var pending = Task.Run(() => RaiseNewCardGroupAddedNotification(account, user, moveCardInput.TargetNewCardGroupName));
await RaiseCardAddedToCardGroupNotification(account, user, currentCardGroupName, cardPansList, cardList.ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);
await pending.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Essentially what this does is:

- start A over on the thread-pool
- start B from the current thread and await completion of B
- await completion of A, so that everything is accounted for

However, note that not all code is designed for concurrency, and how this behaves is *entirely down to your code*. Usually, the intent of `await` is to implement asynchronicity *without* any complexities of concurrency.